# Why wouldn't an upvote change my total score?

Tags: support, voting

I noticed yesterday an answer I had given was upvoted, however, I also see that my total points never changed for that answer.  Why is that?

Sometimes I see a lag in getting the points assigned, but it's been over a day now and it's still not showing up.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Link to the answer? Did it happen to be community wiki?

Comment: Yes, I see that it's marked Community Wiki.  I hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: I've removed the auto-wiki from the answer for you.

Comment: I didn't know what community wiki was before, but I'm here to help as well as get points for Q&A.  If it's better as a wiki for everyone, then you can leave it.